# Make XY Event Layer in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: geoprocessing, xy, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS pro for the first time. I have a csv excel sheet with X, Y and ID.

I have tried to make an XY event layer but I get the 000055 error

How do I add xy data in this system?[image]

Comment: Yes, its the correct error code

Comment: Have you tried to run the tool from a geodatabase table instead to see if that works - the error message suggests you cannot make a Query Table directly from a CSV. Then perhaps put a ticket into ESRI asking why Make XY Event Layer cannot accept a CSV file.

Comment: Based on your error, I didn't expect this to work with CSV files, but it does when I try it. Is your scratch workspace set to a folder instead of a FileGDB?

Comment: As @EvilGenius says try changing your workspace and then try  one of the following workflows again:

1. Add Data > hit ‘Data’ > Select table > Right click table select ‘Display XY Data' from TOC > Run GP tool

2. Add Data dropdown > click ‘XY Event Data’ > Select the table > Run GP tool

Comment: My default geodatabase is a .gdb file. That's okay right? I'm thinking that maybe its a problem with excel itself because under 'status' the file says that it is 'not editable'

Comment: Output database doesn't matter. The tool creates an in_memory layer based on the "Layer_Name" param

Comment: This works just fine for me. I can't find TM65_Irish_Grid. I can find TM75, not 65. Is this a custom projection? Will the tool run if you set as "GCS_WGS_1984"?

Comment: No it doesn't work when I try the GCS_WGS. No its not a custom, TM65 is the revised irish grid in 2005, I didn't even type that in, that comes from the shape file, or else Arc just reads it that way. I reinstalled excel etc just incase that was an issue, but it is still not working

Comment: Pro won't read any coordinate system (spatial reference) info in the csv file (normally it's not there anyway). Could it be the map's coordinate system? Can you post a sample point from the csv file?

Comment: Thank you for all the help. But because of time constraints, I have downloaded a more basic version of GIS and it is working fine.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in ArcGIS Pro. I've ran into it and moving a csv into a File Geodatabase doesn't help. One other item of note, is that I have two csv files, from the same location, one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Without a series of steps that could be followed to try and reproduce this I think we need to close it as non-reproducible.  Feel free to [edit] your question to trigger review for re-opening at any time.